# Repeated executions of custom functions in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

I created a custom function in Google Apps Script to find "Lot Numbers" associated with "Description" strings in a given range. The function outputs as intended, but I noticed in my Logs that the function seems to be called every few minutes.

[Screenshot of my logs with repeated calls to the custom function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8jcP.png)

Is this normal for functions or is it impacting performance of my Spreadsheet? Here is the full source code for my project.

```
/**
     * @param {range} descriptions The range containing descriptions from Ledger
     * @return The lot numbers associated with each description
     * @customfunction
     */
    function findLots(descriptions) {
      Logger.log(input + typeof(input))
      const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
      let thisSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Lots for Descriptions")
      
      const LedgerData = ss.getSheetByName("Ledger").getDataRange().getValues()
      const ledgerMap =  { 
                          date:0,sku:1,description:2,coa:3,expiration:4,
                          quantity:5,packUnit:6, section:7,lot:8,vendor:9,
                          price:10,job:11,comment:12,componentType:13, allocated:14,
                        }
      
      let output = []
      descriptions.forEach(function(entry) {
        let description = entry[0]
        let workingData = LedgerData.map(x => x)
        let lotsFound = []
        while (true){
          let matchingDescIndex = workingData.findIndex(el => el[ledgerMap.description] == description)
          // description doesn't exist
          if (matchingDescIndex === -1) {
            lotsFound = lotsFound.filter(x => x != "")
            // Logger.log("description not found")
            break
          }
          else {
            let thisLot = workingData[matchingDescIndex][ledgerMap.lot]
            if (!lotsFound.includes(thisLot)){
              lotsFound.push(thisLot)
              // Logger.log("added: " + thisLot)
            }
          }
          
          // blank out this row to continue search in next loop iteration
          workingData.splice(matchingDescIndex, 1)
        }
        output.push(lotsFound)
        Logger.log(description + ": " + lotsFound)
      })
      return output
      
    }
```

Comment: Yes, google sheets recalculate every function every x time. If you don't want that, you can write the values back to the sheet as static data.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Do you know if that "x time" is variable and available to be adjusted?

Answer (score 0):

I obvious I can't test this but I think it does the same thing your function was attempting to do.  But if it works, it should run considerably faster.  It completely eliminated the while loop.  You were also doing some unnecessary operations like removing lines from the original data with a splice.

```
function findLots(descriptions) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Ledger");
  const vs = sh.getDataRange().getValues()
  const dvs = sh.getRange(1, 3, sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  const ledgerMap = { date: 0, sku: 1, description: 2, coa: 3, expiration: 4, quantity: 5, packUnit: 6, section: 7, lot: 8, vendor: 9, price: 10, job: 1, comment: 12, componentType: 13, allocated: 14 }
  let lotsFound = [];
  descriptions.forEach(function (entry) {
    let idx = dvs.indexOf(entry[0]);
    if (~idx && !~lotsFound.indexOf(vs[idx][ledgerMap.lot])) {
      lotsFound.push(vs[idx][ledgerMap.lot]);
    }    
  });
  return lotsFound;
}
```

Comment: Cooper, thanks for the suggestion! I compared the output with my original function and it doesn't have the same result. If you wanted to look, here is a google sheet with comparison. 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qxxR3y_yhQruXRrz6TtJ_OYvZrCvRuftt2X6zvSnhRA/edit?usp=sharing